# Chechbox is cheched but content cant slide

Tags: html, css, checkbox

this is my very first question! Is now a couple of days that I am facing a problem`enter code here` with checkbox creating a slide up/down mobile first menu.
The checkbox is working perfectly but what I am unable to do after is letting the menu slide up and done when checkbox is checked.
Any hint or help for the right direction would be greately appreciated!

```
<!-- === MENUTOGGLE === -->
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="menuToggle" value="value">
<label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>
<!--  ==== HEADER ==== -->    
<header>
  <div id="logo" class="brand">
    <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hello"></h1>
  </div>`enter code here`
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

---

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  color: #444;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 400;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
}

.menu-icon {
  float: right;
  color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: none;
}

#menuToggle:checked + .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: -66px;
}

#logo {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  float: none;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(171, 193, 242, 0.1);
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

/*------------ MEDIUM BIG SCREEN -----------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  #logo {
    float: left;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: inherit;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul {
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: right;
    padding: 0.55em 3em 0.55em 1.5em;
    height: 70px;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 3em;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified few lines of your code. Just check below or https://jsfiddle.net/pr7xf32q/, if this is what you expect.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  color: #444;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 400;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
}

.menu-icon {
  float: right;
  color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ header .menu {
  display: block;
}


#logo {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  float: none;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(171, 193, 242, 0.1);
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

/*------------ MEDIUM BIG SCREEN -----------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  #logo {
    float: left;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: inherit;
    display: block;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }


  header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul {
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: right;
    padding: 0.55em 3em 0.55em 1.5em;
    height: 70px;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 3em;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="menuToggle" value="value">
<label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>
<!--  ==== HEADER ==== -->    
<header>
  <div id="logo" class="brand">
    <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hello"></h1>
  </div>
  
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes! And the magic happens! Thank you very much! If I am correct the problem I faced was in the class menu? Could you please explain me what you've done. I feel that after two days pursuing the problem my head is full of numbers and concepts that I'm unable to understand where I was and where I am going. Time to call it a stop till tomorrow. Thank you again))

Comment: And now there is the main problem. Because of the mobile first responsiveness I want the property of the checkbox to be applied only and exclusively to the mobile view. Currently, if the checkbox is unchecked the menu on the desktop view disappears and I don't want so. I don't want the answer but rather an indication about what to search for. I already did the same project using jquery but I want this one to be pure html5 and css3. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked. I have added .menu {  display: none;} and forgot to add in media query for medium and large device. Now updated the code to display:block in media query. Please check and let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: Hi San, it works. One thing. I added display:inline and it worked as display:block. I think there isn't any big difference or maybe I am wrong? Anyway, thanks.